# Переклад "заключение следства" українською мовою

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, from-russian

Часто зустрічала переклад російського словосполучення "заключение следства" як "заключення слідства", окрім того, є ще вживання "обвинувачувальне заключення".

У СУМ не знайшла тлумачення слова "заключення". Цікавить, чи властиве українській мові вживання "заключення" в контексті слідства.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знайшла кілька джерел щодо цього питання. І основна думка всюди збігається. В [Уроках української мови](https://budueba.com/lessons.html) вона звучить так:

Висновок – заключення

Висновок – остаточна думка про що-небудь, логічний підсумок, зроблений на основі спостережень, міркувань або розгляду певних фактів. Прийти до висновку, дійти висновку, практичні висновки.

Часто замість висновок мовці невиправдано вживають віддієслівний іменник заключення. Його, як і слова заключати, нема в українській літературній мові. Неправильно: заключення першого розділу, в заключенні до книжки. Треба: висновки першого розділу, у висновках до книжки тощо. Договір, угоду не заключають, а укладають. І в багатьох інших випадках замість заключати, заключити слід ставити робити висновок, зробити висновок. “З досвіду минулого можна заключити (нормативно: зробити висновок), що до весни маємо готуватися ще взимку” (з газети).

Прикметник заключний, хоч він і потрапив до наших словників, є звичайнісінькою калькою з російського заключительный. Цю лексему потрібно замінювати такими українськими відповідниками, як завершальний, кінцевий, прикінцевий, підсумковий тощо. Наприклад, заключний концерт – завершальний концерт; заключне слово – кінцеве (прикінцеве) слово; заключні заняття – підсумкові заняття.

Також схожу думку можна почитати [тут](https://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/934979.html).

У [російсько-українському словнику](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) українськими відповідником до "заключение" є наступні терміни:

1) (в тюрьму и т. п.) ув’я́знення, зачиня́ння (оконч. зачи́нення), замика́ння (замкне́ння, замкнуття́), завдава́ння (завдання́), закида́ння (заки́нення) до в’язни́ці. [Поста́вився до свого́ ув’я́знення цілко́м байду́жно].
• Тюремное -ние – (тюре́мне) ув’я́знення, в’яз(н)е́ння, замкне́ння.[Сажа́є її́ у тяжке́ в’язе́ння (О. Левиц.)].
• Домашнее -ние – домо́ве в’яз(н)е́ння (О. Левиц.).
• Одиночное -ние – само́тнє замкне́ння.
• Предварительное -ние – досудо́ве́ замкне́ння, попере́днє ув’я́знення (замкне́ння).
• Наказать тюремным -нием – покара́ти в’язни́цею.
• Подвергнуть -нию – замкну́ти, забра́ти (узя́ти) до в’язни́ці, в тюрму́, за сторо́жу, (гал.) да́ти за ключ;
2) (вывод) ви́сновок (-новку). [Яки́й ви́сновок тре́ба зроби́ти з ва́ших слів?
 Ви́сновок експе́ртної комі́сії. Ви́сновок прокуро́ра]. 
• Вывести -ние – зроби́ти ви́сновок, ви́снувати.
• Давать своё -ние – подава́ти свій ви́сновок, висло́влювати (подава́ти) свою́ ду́мку.
• На ваше -ние – на ва́шу ду́мку, на ваш ви́сновок;
3) кіне́ць (-нця́), закі́нчення.
• В -ние – в кінці́ всьо́го, на закі́нчення, наоста́нці, наоста́нку, напослі́док, напри́кінці.
• -ние счетов – замкне́ння раху́нків.
• Выпить в -ние – ви́пити наоста́нку, на поту́ху;
4) -ние условия, договора, контракта – склада́ння умо́ви, догово́ру, контра́кту, підпи́сування, підписа́ння умо́ви, догово́ру, контра́кту.
• -ние мира, перемирия – замире́ння.

**Отже, враховуючи контекст, на мою думку, найкращим варіантом буде *"висновок слідства"*.**